# JSF Number Validation

Tags: jsf

Is there any inbuilt number validator tag in JSF that checks whether an input entered in `h:inputext` field is a number?

The first question was answered. Edited to explain the next problem:

```
<h:inputText id="maxrecs" value="#{simpleBean.numRecords}" required="false" maxlength="4" >                         
    <f:convertNumber longOnly="true"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Backing Bean

```
private long numRecords = null;
```

If I use String or Integer object in the backing bean , value is not being set. Now when I use primitive int, 0 is being printed on the screen. I would like the screen to be empty.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `f:convertNumber` (use the `integerOnly` attribute).

You can get more information [here](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_convertNumber.html).

Comment: use the converterMessage attribute of h:inputText. Add whatever message you want to that attribute.

Comment: Thanks again. The number is associated with a Integer property in the backend. But it is not letting the value to be set. The value is set only if it is converted to primitive int. The problem with primitive int is that it displays 0 in the textbox. Are there any ways to overcome this? Thanks.

Comment: first of all , its a completely new question and you should ask it in a new question but anyways, do mean that the value is not being assigned to the backing bean property?? can you show me some code how you are using it, and explain your problem a bit more?

Comment: The answer to your question is use private Long numRecords in the Bean i.e Long instead of long.
 And for a new question always make a new question, do not add new part in the previous question because your new problem will not be easily searchable in the future

Comment: and also i do not see any reason from the snippet you provided why the String or Integer type property would not be set.

Comment: Thanks a ton Khizar. Works great. I'll keep this in mind next time around.

Answer (score 14):

You can use:

```
 <f:validateLongRange minimum="20" maximum="1000" />
```

Where minimum is the smallest number allowed and maximum is the largest.
[Look here for more details](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/f/validateLongRange.html)

Answer (score 7):

JSF Number validation for inputtext
mention f:converterNumber component in between h inputText component and mention the attributes integerOnly and type.

```
<h:inputText id="textMobileId" label="Mobile" styleClass="controlfont" value="#{UserRegistrationBean.textMobile}">
    <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" type="number" />
</h:inputText>
```

If you enter abcd in Mobile textbox at the time when you click on commandbutton it automatically shows an error like

```
Mobile: 'abcd' is not a number.
```

Comment: I tried like you suggested but did not work. Ok I will try again

Answer (score 3):

i8taken solution converts number into long without validation message (at least in my case: JSF2 / global messages per page). For proper validation message you can 
1. check value in action method in bean;
or 
2. use converter attribute for inputText:

> `<h:inputText id="maxrecs" value="#{simpleBean.numRecords}" maxlength="4" converter="javax.faces.Integer" />`

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the passthrough, so first add this library

```
    xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
```

and after use this

```
   <h:inputText id="numberId" pt:type="number" />
```

Comment: Again, bad formatting... And the question is about VALIDATION (including serverside!)

Comment: when you use passthrough, you can use HTML5 directly and when you click on submit button, then it will validate automatically because the type is number, so this solution is about validation

Comment: But not serverside... so tampering is possible!