# JSF number converter issue

Tags: jsf

I am using jsf number converter in my application as follows:

```
<p:inputText id="hoursWorked" required="true"     
  value="#myBean.hours">               
    <f:convertNumber locale="de" maxFractionDigits="2"/>
</p:inputText>
```

Now , if I enter a value such as 160ffff, the converter automatically strips off the letters after the digits whereas I would like to throw an error. How can I do it?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148661/jsf-number-validation

Comment: This is syntactically incorrect - `value="#myBean.hours"`. It should be a valid EL expression instead such as `value="#{myBean.hours}"`. If you want JSF to issue an error (in the form of a user-friendly error message), when a value of type String supplied by end-users cannot be represented to a number i.e. cannot be parsed to an appropriate numeric type, then it is the job of a converter (which is invoked before a validator) and not the job of a validator. Let a default, built-in converter do its job. If the default converter does not suffice the need, you can always have a custom converter.

Comment: What you want is a validator, not a converter